# How to align three equations?

Tags: equations, tabularx

The last equation is slighter higher placed than the two others and I don't know why.

**Current output**

[image]

**Current code**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}XXX@{}}
  \begin{equation}
    P_1 = \frac{(1+4\omega)^2}{2(3+9\omega)}
  \end{equation} &
    \begin{equation}
    P_2 = \frac{1}{2}-\frac{\omega}{1+4\omega}
  \end{equation} &
      \begin{equation}
    P_3 = \frac{1}{2}
  \end{equation}
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have a look at the `align` environment or other alternatives for the `equation` environment.

Comment: Hmm, but when I plug in a longer expression for P_3 (e.g. the expression for P_1) they are perfectly aligned.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The curious problem is due to the fact that the third equation is quite short, so TeX inserts `\abovedisplayshortskip` instead that `\abovedisplayskip`.

You can do it without `tabularx`: it's just a sequence of minipages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[2]
\[
\setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{\abovedisplayskip}
\setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{\belowdisplayskip}
\begin{minipage}{.33333\textwidth}
  \vspace*{-\baselineskip}
  \begin{equation}
    P_1 = \frac{(1+4\omega)^2}{2(3+9\omega)}
  \end{equation}
\end{minipage}
%
\begin{minipage}{.33333\textwidth}
  \vspace*{-\baselineskip}
  \begin{equation}
  P_2 = \frac{1}{2}-\frac{\omega}{1+4\omega}
  \end{equation}
\end{minipage}
%
\begin{minipage}{.33333\textwidth}
  \vspace*{-\baselineskip}
  \begin{equation}
  P_3 = \frac{1}{2}
  \end{equation}
\end{minipage}
\]
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

The `\vspace*{-\baselineskip}` is necessary to nullify the one line empty paragraph that's inserted before `equation`. Moreover I set `\abovedisplayshortskip` to equal `\abovedisplayskip` and, for symmetry, also the “below” skips.

[image]

After seeing this you might want to manually modify the widths of the minipages. This is with `.35\textwidth` for the first, `.4\textwidth` for the second and `.2\textwidth` for the last one.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I have no idea why it works, but just loading `geometry` solves the problem!!

Actually, I had some time ago defined a `tabequation` environment, more or less defined as in your code, and I always load geometry with option showframe, just to check there's no overflow in the margin. I never observed a similar problem, so I wondered what difference in code explained the behaviour difference.

Just in case you're interested, here are both codes. Note they work with `subequations`, if necessary:

```
        \documentclass{article}
        \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
        \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
        \usepackage{lmodern}%
         \usepackage{tabularx, mathtools}
        \usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

        \newcolumntype{E}[1]{>{\equation}>{\hsize=#1\hsize}X<{\endequation}}
        \newcolumntype{Y}{>{\equation}X<{\endequation}}

        \newenvironment{tabequations}[1]{%
        \vspace{\abovedisplayskip}\par\noindent\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}\setlength\abovedisplayskip{0pt}
        \tabularx{\linewidth}{#1}}%
        {\endtabularx\par}

        \begin{document}

      Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.%

  \begin{subequations}
    \noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}XXX@{}}
      \begin{equation}
        P_1 = \frac{(1+4\omega)^2}{2(3+9\omega)}
      \end{equation} &
        \begin{equation}
        P_2 = \frac{1}{2}-\frac{\omega}{1+4\omega}
      \end{equation} &
          \begin{equation}
        P_3 = \frac{1}{2}
      \end{equation}
    \end{tabularx}
  \end{subequations}
     Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.%
\begin{subequations}
     \begin{tabequations}{@{}*{4}{Y}@{}}
     P_1 = \frac{(1+4\omega)^2}{2(3+9\omega)}
     & P_2 = \frac{1}{2}-\frac{\omega}{1+4\omega}%
     & P_3 = \frac{1}{2}
     \end{tabequations}
\end{subequations}

        \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

With `tabularx` and `gather` instead of `equation` (`gather` has more consistent defined vertical space above and below of a math expression):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text\\
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}XXX@{}}
  \begin{gather}
    P_1 = \frac{(1+4\omega)^2}{2(3+9\omega)}
  \end{gather} &
    \begin{gather}
    P_2 = \frac{1}{2}-\frac{\omega}{1+4\omega}
  \end{gather} &
      \begin{gather}
    P_3 = \frac{1}{2}
  \end{gather}
\end{tabularx}\\
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text

some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
\end{document}
```

[image]